# How to add/modify env variable in oh-my-zsh

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I am using macbook(m1) chip  with `oh-my-zsh`.
How / where can I add a new env variable. For example before using oh-my-zsh, I used to add the following lines in `~./zshrc` and source the file/open a new terminal to reflect the changes.

```
eval "$(~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init - zsh)"
export PATH="$HOME:/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/bin
```